# webclient not login into facebook

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, webclient

i tried login facebook with webclient but its just return login page it is not loged into facebook. What is wrong with my code?

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
collection.Add("email", "sadasfasdaddsfadfdf");
collection.Add("pass", "54");
client.Proxy = null;
byte[] result = client.UploadValues("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1", "POST", collection);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("result.html", result);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("result.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at what browser pass when you click login button in Facebook? I see that they pass some additional data, maybe something like anti-forgery token, etc. Why are you trying to login with web client in that way? What is your goal?
Have you considered Facebook C# SDK?
http://facebooksdk.net/

If you look at the login form source you will notice additional hidden elements:

```
<input name="lsd" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="AVqRJE3k"/>
<input name="lgnrnd" type="hidden" value="100127_w8ha"/>
<input name="lgnjs" id="lgnjs" type="hidden" value="1391191287"/>
```

I don't know the meaning of these fields, but I think some of them put there for secutrity and you can't predict value of them. So, you would need to request login page first, get those values, then send your login request with web client.

Comment: actually it will be example for me i will apply to another website i used facebook because i think that i will be common issue. yes it returns me that site when i click login buton

Comment: I got this value from Document, which contains value="n" everytime
<input name="lgnjs" id="lgnjs" type="hidden" value="n"/>
but some other value is sent while navigating ,Where can i find the real value ,Kindly help me